# How to customise react-bootstrap components?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, inline-styles, react-css-modules

What is the best way to override css classes/customise react-bootstrap components? - (I have read the docs, and unless I am missing something, this isn't covered).

From what I have read, it seems like it's a choice between inline styles (radium) and css modules but which is better and why?

Comment: The topic is subjective. You can go whichever way you want, according to your needs. In our case, the legacy code was using `less`. So we had to override variables.less from bootstrap's source code. We created our own variables.less file which would override variables like @brandPrimary, which is famous bootstrap primary color.

Answer (score 17):

I am not sure if this answers your question but [Documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts/) clearly provide examples. For instance [Button](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/)

**Props**

```
+--------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|  Name  |  Type   | Default| Description                                |
+--------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
|bsClass |  string | 'btn'  | Base CSS class and prefix for the component|
+--------+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------+
```

This one could be modified to add custom CSS class to your Button component. Also component could be changed with setting componentClass.

```
<Button type="submit" onClick={this.submit}
 bsClass='custom-class'
>
</Button>
```

Where `custom-class` is CSS class that could

> provide new, non-Bootstrap, CSS styles for a component.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3hg89yt/2/) with example of how to use `bsClass`.

**Inline styles:**

According to [bug](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2348) filled, inline styles will not be supported officially.

> you want to use the actual style prop. bsClass is for adjusting the
>   way bootstrap css classes are applied to the components not inline
>   styles

But [issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1549) states that:

> You're free to use them if you want. We have no formal opinion.

**NOTE** Not all components provided by react-bootstrap allow class customization through `bsClass`, for example [Breadcrumb](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/breadcrumb/)

Comment: I'm not sure that is entirely correct - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#custom-styles.

Comment: @AloeVeraForty I think that's depend on which particular case you have. Both are valid.

Comment: With the method you're suggesting, is it possible to use inline styles? - it would be helpful if you could provide some example code >>>

Comment: appreciate that. thanks! but there is no way to do override default styling using inline styles with react-bootstrap..?

Comment: ah ok, I've found out that you use the 'style' prop as opposed to bsClass - thanks for the help

Comment: Do all React component has bsClass property?

Comment: @AloeVeraForty The link is broken.

Comment: As the year of CoViD-19, the correct prop is `bsPrefix`

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer to this for most people (like me) is that one can add custom styles to react-bootstrap components using the `style` prop. E.g. for a default Button with blue text:

```
<Button bsStyle="default" style={style.blueButton}>Button Text</Button>
```

or

```
<Button bsStyle="default" style={{color:"blue"}}>Button Text</Button>
```

Answer (score 7):

> Example With SCSS

According to React Bootstrap [Docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#customize-bootstrap) you can create a custom class with the property bsPrefix="custom-class".

Then in your stylesheet, you can override styles taking advantage of css specificity

```
 import styles from './RocketCard.module.scss';

 function RocketCard({ name }) { return (
     <div className={styles.rocketCardContainer}>
      {name}
      <Card className={styles.customCard} bsPrefix="customCard">
        <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and 
            make up the 
            bulk of the card's
            content.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
     </div>
    );
    }



// SCSS File
.rocketCardContainer {
  background-color: red;
  .customCard {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I searched few blogs and the answer i got was to !important.
I was looking for a more general solution, but have not found any other solution other than adding !important to each and every element we want to override.

```
.form-control { 
  border-radius: 30px !important;
  background-color: #f4f6f5 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React-bootstrap has NavLink component on it, you have to import it first.

when you generate Boostrap code for navlink using something like rt4-nav the NavLink component comes with className="nav-link" which contains all the styles, you can then override the class as shown below.

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`
`import { NavLink } from 'react-bootstrap';`

```
  <NavMenu className="d-flex">
      <NavLink className="nav-link">
          Inspirations
      </NavLink>
  </NavMenu>

const NavMenu = styled.div`
    .nav-link {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
`;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You should import first. An example, if your import order is like this:

```
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

The things you write in `index.css` will be invalid unless they are `!important`.

But if you write it like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
```

You can override Bootstrap however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can search up the specific component on the react-bootstrap website:

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/alerts

At the bottom of each page there is an API section which gives the default value for the bsPrefix. You can then alter this default value in your CSS file.

For example, the default bsPrefix for the Button and Tooltip components are 'btn' and 'tooltip' respectively. In the CSS file you can edit the component styles using .btn{background-color: purple;} or .tooltip{background-color: purple;}

Comment: For clear understanding, Any code written in your answer should bd well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import classes from './signInForm.module.css'
```

is working for me Thank you very much